# Comparing medians from two groups

Tags: r, ordinal-data, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, median

Hi: I have a survey where respondents were asked to rank a series of statements in terms of how much they agreed with them. There were seven statements. So, for each of seven statements, each respondent has value that ranges from 1 to 7, depending on where they ranked that item.  Two questions: first, should I conceive of this as an ordinal or an interval level variable.  I'm inclined to think of it as an ordinal variable, because I'm not sure how meaningful a mean is in this context.  It seems more intuitive to say the median ranking of this group of respondents' for this statement was 2, compared to 5 for a different group, rather than, say, 3.6 compared to 5.5, or whatever.

So, my first question is, is that sound logic?

The second question flows from this: If I do conceive of this as an ordinal level variable, rather than an interval, what statistical test can I use to test for difference in median values? I have read a little bit that refers to a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test for difference in medians, but I'm not sure if that is proper for a cross-sectional survey of around 150 people at the same point in time.

Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: I would consider interpreting the ranking as the realization of a latent scoring process. Then your null hypothesis can be formulated in terms of the latent score.

Comment: This is not really all that helpful to me. I don't really know what a latent scoring process is.

Comment: Sure but you can make a reasonable guess. For instance, you could assume that each group scores each item with an exponential distribution with a given mean per item and then orders the result. 

Null hypothesis only makes it *look* like you're agnostic about the hypothesis.

Comment: Actually, I lied. I probably won't.  I'm not a statistician, in fact, I'm entirely self-taught.  This analysis is for a journal that is not primarily statistical.  I'm just trying to do my level best to do the best analysis possible, without going off on a wild goose chase learning some obscure statistical procedure. I did that once trying to learn how to do survival analysis properly. It took me months.  Is there something wrong with doing either a difference in median or mean analysis like I presented?

Answer (score 3):

> I have read a little bit that refers to a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test for difference in medians

The Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney is not a test for equality of medians, it's a test for one variable being stochastically larger than another ($P(X>Y)>P(Y>X)$). If you're using it as a location test, it's actually a test for a zero (population) median of pairwise differences.

If you make the additional assumption of identical distributions apart from a location shift then it will be a test of medians (but it would also be a test of means, as long as population means exist).

> I have a survey where respondents were asked to rank a series of statements in terms of how much they agreed with them. There were seven statements. So, for each of seven statements, each respondent has value that ranges from 1 to 7, depending on where they ranked that item.

So that's seven numbers per respondent. What did you do with those 7 numbers?

> first, should I conceive of this as an ordinal or an interval level variable.

If you just added the scores on each item, you already assumed the 7 items were interval scale when you did that.

> because I'm not sure how meaningful a mean is in this context.

If you can add a "2" and "6" and get the same result as when you got a "3" and "5", then everything needed for a mean to be meaningful was already assumed to be true.

> It seems more intuitive to say the median ranking of this group of respondents' for this statement was 2, compared to 5 for a different group, rather than, say, 3.6 compared to 5.5, or whatever.

If you find a median intuitive, that's fine, there's nothing stopping you working with medians -- that doesn't require you to assume it ordinal even though you already made it interval.

You can always consider a permutation test; it assumes exchangeability under the null, which is a somewhat stronger assumption than the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney needs.